# A/B Testing Issue in Alexa Skills

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I created an A/B Test for my skill to observe the impact of a new change on the customers. I created a test and piloted it with 0% Traffic exposure for 2 weeks for testing it on development before pushing it to Live stage. But, since I started the test I am now unable to stop/delete the test before the its decided lifespan(2 Weeks). For me the delete button for the A/B test is disable from Alexa Developer console. I have tried stopping the test using ASK CLI command "ask smapi delete-experiment -s  --experiment-id " but it response with "The experiment is ineligible to DELETE at current state". Here are the screen shot from both Developer console and ASK CLI. I am now unable to create another test since this test in already in progress. Can someone help me out here? Thank you in advance![tag:alexa[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erUfG.png)]

I should be able to stop the piloted A/B Test before its alotted period with ASK CLI or Developer console.

Answer (score 1):

For Delete an A/B test and CLI command for "delete-experiment", it's my understanding that you can only call this API if your test is in CREATED state. Alternatively, since I also understand you have started test for decided lifespan(2 Weeks)and would like to stop/delete it before end, it might be helpful to:

1. Use "[manage-experiment-state](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/a-b-test-your-skill-cli.html#manage-experiment-state)" CLI command or ["Update A/B test state"](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/a-b-test-your-skill-apis.html#update-ab-test-state) to update current state of A/B test from "Running" to "Created". [Accepted target-state values: ENABLED, RUNNING, STOPPED]
2. With A/B Test state set back to "CREATED", use "[delete-experiment](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/a-b-test-your-skill-cli.html#delete-experiment)" CLI command or "[Delete A/B test"](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/a-b-test-your-skill-apis.html#delete-ab-test) in order to Delete existing A/B test.

If you need to delete your test after you start it (meaning your test is in the RUNNING state), you must completely delete your skill with the Delete skill manifest REST API. See more info here: [Delete A/B test](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/a-b-test-your-skill-apis.html#delete-ab-test)

Since issue might be related with A/B Test in running state after having been started, I would recommend trying to update state back to "CREATED" before deleting it if necessary assuming you are not looking to delete skill entirely.